# How get input value in Tilda?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

There is a site builder in which it is impossible to get the form input through the DOM. What to do? :)

This code return nothing:

```
$('form').change(function() {
    alert('email input value: ' + $(this).find('input[name=Email]').attr('value'));
    alert('name input value: ' + $(this).find('input[name=Name]').attr('value'));
    alert('phone input value: ' + $(this).find('input[name=Phone]').attr('value'));
});
```

Demo: http://project282540.tilda.ws/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `<input>`'s value, you need to use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`:

```
$('form').change(function() {
  alert('email input value: ' + 
      $(this).find('input[name=Email]').val());
  alert('name input value: ' + 
      $(this).find('input[name=Name]').val());
  alert('phone input value: ' + 
      $(this).find('input[name=Phone]').val());
});
```

`.attr('value')` means the attribute defined in HTML. As there is no `value` attribute value in HTML's input tags, `.attr('value')` will always return empty string.

Here is a small experiment: edit the HTML in http://project282540.tilda.ws/ and put `value` property to one of the input tags. Then, when the form is changed, that newly added `value` attribute will be alerted.

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

This should work though I am not sure about the site builder.

```
$(".t-submit").on({
    click: function() {
    $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).val())
    })
  }
})
```